# Strings in Matlab table

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string of alphabets e.g.

```
  S = ['a';'b';'c';'d';'e'];
```

and I want to put it in column 3 in the table:

```
  table(:,1) = M1;  table(:,2) = d1;
  disp(table)
```

`M1` and `d1` are `5 X 1` matrices of numbers each.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html?s_tid=doc_12b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think to do as follows:

```
r = {M1, d1, S};
```

or

```
r = {M1; d1; S};
```

**EDIT**

you may also do this:

```
 M1 = rand(5,1);
 d1 = rand(5,1);
 S = ['a';'b';'c';'d';'e'];
 y =  arrayfun(@(i) {M1(i), d1(i), S(i)'},1:5,'UniformOutput',false);
 res = cat(1,y{:});
```

I'd suggest this approach to solve your question.

Comment: @raj: you may consider the idea of rating my answer as the accepted one